# IPOPT does not obey constraints but does not record the violation when using CppAD

Tags: c++, optimization, polynomial-math, ipopt

I am trying to evaluate the coefficients and time of two fifth-order polynomials (one each for x and y position) that minimizes effort and time (the objective function) when connecting an initial position, velocity, and orientation to a desired final position and orientation with 0 velocity (equality constraints).  Here is the code:

```
#include <vector>
#include <cppad/cppad.hpp>
#include <cppad/ipopt/solve.hpp>

using CppAD::AD;

typedef struct {
    double x, y, theta, linear_velocity;
} Waypoint;

typedef std::vector<Waypoint> WaypointList;

struct TrajectoryConfig {
    //! gain on accumulated jerk term in cost function
    double Kj;
    //! gain on time term in cost function
    double Kt;
    //! gain on terminal velocity term in cost function
    double Kv;
};

class Trajectory {
 public:
     explicit Trajectory(TrajectoryConfig config);
     ~Trajectory();
     void updateConfigs(TrajectoryConfig config);
     void solve(WaypointList waypoints);
 private:
     //! solution vector
     std::vector<double> solution_;
     //! gain on accumulated jerk term in cost function
     double Kj_;
     //! gain on time term in cost function
     double Kt_;
     //! gain on terminal velocity term in cost function
     double Kv_;
};

/*
  Trajectory(TrajectoryConfig)

  class constructor.  Initializes class given configuration struct
*/
Trajectory::Trajectory(TrajectoryConfig config) {
    Kj_ = config.Kj;
    Kt_ = config.Kt;
    Kv_ = config.Kv;
}

Trajectory::~Trajectory() {
    std::cerr << "Trajectory Destructor!" << std::endl;
}

enum Indices { A0 = 0, A1, A2, A3, A4, A5, B0, B1, B2, B3, B4, B5, T };

class FGradEval {
 public:
     size_t M_;
     // gains on cost;
     double Kj_, Kt_;
     // constructor
     FGradEval(double Kj, double Kt) {
         M_ = 13;  // no. of parameters per trajectory segment: 2 x 6 coefficients + 1 time
         Kj_ = Kj;
         Kt_ = Kt;
     }

     typedef CPPAD_TESTVECTOR(AD<double>) ADvector;
     void operator()(ADvector& fgrad, const ADvector& vars) { 
         fgrad[0] = 0;

         AD<double> accum_jerk;
         AD<double> a0, a1, a2, a3, a4, a5;
         AD<double> b0, b1, b2, b3, b4, b5;
         AD<double> T, T2, T3, T4, T5;
         AD<double> x, y, vx, vy;

         size_t offset = 1;

         a0 = vars[Indices::A0];
         a1 = vars[Indices::A1];
         a2 = vars[Indices::A2];
         a3 = vars[Indices::A3];
         a4 = vars[Indices::A4];
         a5 = vars[Indices::A5];
         b0 = vars[Indices::B0];
         b1 = vars[Indices::B1];
         b2 = vars[Indices::B2];
         b3 = vars[Indices::B3];
         b4 = vars[Indices::B4];
         b5 = vars[Indices::B5];
         T  = vars[Indices::T];
         T2 = T*T;
         T3 = T*T2;
         T4 = T*T3;
         T5 = T*T4;

         x    = a0 + a1*T + a2*T2 + a3*T3 + a4*T4 + a5*T5;
         y    = b0 + b1*T + b2*T2 + b3*T3 + b4*T4 + b5*T5;
         vx   = a1 + 2*a2*T + 3*a3*T2 + 4*b4*T3 + 5*a5*T4;
         vy   = b1 + 2*b2*T + 3*b3*T2 + 4*b4*T3 + 5*b5*T4;

         //! cost-terms
         //! accum_jerk is the analytic integral of int_0^T (jerk_x^2 + jerk_y^2) dt
         accum_jerk = 36 * T * (a3*a3 + b3*b3) + 144 * T2 * (a3*a4 + b3*b4) + T3 * (240*(a3*a5 + b3*b5) + 192*(a4*a4 + b4*b4))
             + 720 * T4 * (a4*a5 + b4*b5) + 720 * T5 * (a5*a5 + b5*b5);
         fgrad[0] += Kj_ * accum_jerk;
         fgrad[0] += Kt_ * T;

         //! initial equality constraints
         fgrad[offset]     = vars[Indices::A0];
         fgrad[1 + offset] = vars[Indices::B0];
         fgrad[2 + offset] = vars[Indices::A1];
         fgrad[3 + offset] = vars[Indices::B1];
         offset += 4;

         //! terminal inequality constraints
         fgrad[offset]     = x;
         fgrad[offset + 1] = y;
         fgrad[offset + 2] = vx;
         fgrad[offset + 3] = vy;
     }
};

void Trajectory::solve(WaypointList waypoints) {
    if (waypoints.size() != 2) {
        std::cerr << "Trajectory::solve - Function requires 2 waypoints." << std::endl;
        return;
    }

    //! status flag for solution
    bool ok;
    //! typedef for ipopt/cppad
    typedef CPPAD_TESTVECTOR(double) Dvector;
    //! no. of variables for optimization problem
    size_t n_vars = 13;
    //! no. of constraints
    size_t n_cons = 4 * 2;  // the start and final waypoint each contribute 4 constraints (x, y, theta, v) -> (x, y, vx, vy)
    //! create vector container for optimizer solution
    //! and initialize it to zero
    Dvector vars(n_vars);
    for (size_t i = 0; i < n_vars; i++) {
        vars[i] = 0;
    }

    //! set initial state (this will only determine the first two coefficients of the initial polynomials)
    double v = (fabs(waypoints[0].linear_velocity) < 1e-3)
        ? 1e-3 : waypoints[0].linear_velocity;
    vars[Indices::A0] = waypoints[0].x;
    vars[Indices::B0] = waypoints[0].y;
    vars[Indices::A1] = v * cos(waypoints[0].theta);
    vars[Indices::B1] = v * sin(waypoints[0].theta);
    vars[Indices::T] = 0;
    //! there are no explicit bounds on vars, so set to something large for the optimizer
    //! we could perhaps put bounds on the coeffs corresponding to acc, jerk, snap, ..
    Dvector vars_lb(n_vars);
    Dvector vars_ub(n_vars);

    for (size_t i = 0; i < n_vars; i++) {
        vars_lb[i] = -1e10;
        vars_ub[i] =  1e10;
    }

    //! time must be non-negative!
    vars_lb[Indices::T] = 0;

    //! set the bounds on the constraints
    Dvector cons_lb(n_cons);
    Dvector cons_ub(n_cons);

    //! offset term on index
    size_t offset = 0;

    //! initial equality constraint - we must start from where we are!
    cons_lb[0] = waypoints[0].x;
    cons_ub[0] = waypoints[0].x;

    cons_lb[1] = waypoints[0].y;
    cons_ub[1] = waypoints[0].y;

    cons_lb[2] = v * cos(waypoints[0].theta);
    cons_ub[2] = v * cos(waypoints[0].theta);

    cons_lb[3] = v * sin(waypoints[0].theta);
    cons_ub[3] = v * sin(waypoints[0].theta);

    offset += 4;

    //! terminal point
    cons_lb[offset] = waypoints[1].x;
    cons_ub[offset] = waypoints[1].x;

    cons_lb[offset + 1] = waypoints[1].y;
    cons_ub[offset + 1] = waypoints[1].y;

    cons_lb[offset + 2] = 1e-3 * cos(waypoints[1].theta);
    cons_ub[offset + 2] = 1e-3 * cos(waypoints[1].theta);

    cons_lb[offset + 3] = 1e-3 * sin(waypoints[1].theta);
    cons_ub[offset + 3] = 1e-3 * sin(waypoints[1].theta);

    //! create instance of objective function class
    FGradEval fg_eval(Kj_, Kt_);

    //! IPOPT INITIALIZATION
    std::string options;
    options += "Integer print_level  5\n";
    options += "Sparse  true        forward\n";
    options += "Sparse  true        reverse\n";
    options += "Integer max_iter         100\n";
    // options += "Numeric tol         1e-4\n";

    //! compute the solution
    CppAD::ipopt::solve_result<Dvector> solution;

    //! solve
    CppAD::ipopt::solve<Dvector, FGradEval>(
            options, vars, vars_lb, vars_ub, cons_lb, cons_ub, fg_eval, solution);

    //! check if the solver was successful
    ok = solution.status == CppAD::ipopt::solve_result<Dvector>::success;

    //! if the solver was unsuccessful, exit
    //! this case will be handled by calling method
    if (!ok) {
        std::cerr << "Trajectory::solve - Failed to find a solution!" << std::endl;
        return;
    }

    //! (DEBUG) output the final cost
    std::cout << "Final Cost: " << solution.obj_value << std::endl;

    //! populate output with argmin vector
    for (size_t i = 0; i < n_vars; i++) {
        solution_.push_back(solution.x[i]);
    }

    return;
}
```

Where I am having problems is in the following:

1. The initial equality constraint (starting position, velocity, and orientation) is being upheld, while the terminal velocity constraint is not.  The algorithm terminates at the correct final (x,y,angle), but the velocity is not zero.  I have looked through the code and I cannot understand why the position and orientation at the endpoint would be obeyed while the velocity would not.  My suspicion is that my definition of the equality constraints is not what I think it is.
2. The problem does not converge regularly, but this seems a fairly simple problem as defined (see output)

> ```
> ******************************************************************************
> This program contains Ipopt, a library for large-scale nonlinear optimization.
>  Ipopt is released as open source code under the Eclipse Public License (EPL).
>          For more information visit http://projects.coin-or.org/Ipopt
> ******************************************************************************
>
> This is Ipopt version 3.11.9, running with linear solver mumps.
> NOTE: Other linear solvers might be more efficient (see Ipopt documentation).
>
> Number of nonzeros in equality constraint Jacobian...:       30
> Number of nonzeros in inequality constraint Jacobian.:        0
> Number of nonzeros in Lagrangian Hessian.............:       23
>
> Total number of variables............................:       13
>                      variables with only lower bounds:        0
>                 variables with lower and upper bounds:       13
>                      variables with only upper bounds:        0
> Total number of equality constraints.................:        8
> Total number of inequality constraints...............:        0
>         inequality constraints with only lower bounds:        0
>    inequality constraints with lower and upper bounds:        0
>         inequality constraints with only upper bounds:        0
>
> iter    objective    inf_pr   inf_du lg(mu)  ||d||  lg(rg) alpha_du alpha_pr  ls
>    0  9.9999900e-03 1.00e+00 5.00e-04  -1.0 0.00e+00    -  0.00e+00 0.00e+00   0
>    1  5.9117705e-02 1.00e+00 1.20e+02  -1.0 5.36e+07    -  1.04e-05 7.63e-06f 18
>    2  1.1927070e+00 1.00e+00 2.62e+06  -1.0 9.21e+05  -4.0 6.16e-15 2.29e-23H  1
>    3  2.9689692e-01 1.00e+00 1.80e+05  -1.0 2.24e+13    -  1.83e-07 8.42e-10f 20
>    4r 2.9689692e-01 1.00e+00 1.00e+03  -0.0 0.00e+00    -  0.00e+00 4.58e-07R 11
>    5r 2.1005820e+01 9.99e-01 5.04e+02  -0.0 6.60e-02    -  9.90e-01 4.95e-01f  2
>    6r 7.7118141e+04 9.08e-01 5.18e+03  -0.0 2.09e+00    -  4.21e-01 1.00e+00f  1
>    7r 1.7923891e+04 7.82e-01 1.54e+03  -0.0 3.63e+00    -  9.90e-01 1.00e+00f  1
>    8r 5.9690221e+03 5.41e-01 5.12e+02  -0.0 2.92e+00    -  9.90e-01 1.00e+00f  1
>    9r 4.6855625e+03 5.54e-01 1.95e+02  -0.0 5.14e-01    -  9.92e-01 1.00e+00f  1
> iter    objective    inf_pr   inf_du lg(mu)  ||d||  lg(rg) alpha_du alpha_pr  ls
>   10r 8.4901226e+03 5.55e-01 5.18e+01  -0.0 2.24e-01    -  1.00e+00 1.00e+00f  1
>
> Number of Iterations....: 10
>
>                                    (scaled)                 (unscaled)
> Objective...............:   8.4901225582208808e+03    8.4901225582208808e+03
> Dual infeasibility......:   6.3613117039244315e+06    6.3613117039244315e+06
> Constraint violation....:   5.5503677023620179e-01    5.5503677023620179e-01
> Complementarity.........:   9.9999982900301554e-01    9.9999982900301554e-01
> Overall NLP error.......:   6.3613117039244315e+06    6.3613117039244315e+06
>
>
> Number of objective function evaluations             = 43
> Number of objective gradient evaluations             = 6
> Number of equality constraint evaluations            = 71
> Number of inequality constraint evaluations          = 0
> Number of equality constraint Jacobian evaluations   = 12
> Number of inequality constraint Jacobian evaluations = 0
> Number of Lagrangian Hessian evaluations             = 10
> Total CPU secs in IPOPT (w/o function evaluations)   =      0.006
> Total CPU secs in NLP function evaluations           =      0.001
>
> EXIT: Maximum Number of Iterations Exceeded.
> ```

I am not looking for an answer to my problem specifically.  What I am hoping for are some suggestions as to why my problem may not be working as expected.  Specifically, do my constraints make sense, as defined?  Is the variable initialization done properly?

Comment: While looking for IPOPTs virtual methods which need to be overloaded i realized, that you are using CppAD and a lot of magic is being done under the hood. Sadly there seems to be no tag for that lib here, but i think you really should add this information in the title (for potential experts).

Comment: Thanks for your comment @sascha.  My next step will to actually explicitly define the gradients and overload the appropriate virtual methods that you mention (e.g. eval_f, eval_g, etc...).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was in the following lines:

```
 x    = a0 + a1*T + a2*T2 + a3*T3 + a4*T4 + a5*T5;
 y    = b0 + b1*T + b2*T2 + b3*T3 + b4*T4 + b5*T5;
 vx   = a1 + 2*a2*T + 3*a3*T2 + 4*b4*T3 + 5*a5*T4;
 vy   = b1 + 2*b2*T + 3*b3*T2 + 4*b4*T3 + 5*b5*T4;
```

Specifically,

```
vx   = a1 + 2*a2*T + 3*a3*T2 + 4*b4*T3 + 5*a5*T4;
```

should be

```
vx   = a1 + 2*a2*T + 3*a3*T2 + 4*a4*T3 + 5*a5*T4;
```

based upon the mapping of a's to the x-coordinate and b's to the y-coordinate.

This fixed the problem of constraint violation.

With regards to the problem of convergence/feasibility, I found that ensuring that the initial guess is in the feasible set (obeys the equality constraints) fixed this problem; measures of optimizer performance (inf_pr and inf_du, etc...) were much smaller after fixing the initial condition.